# How to get server url in model of ZF2

Tags: php, oop, url, model, zend-framework2

I want to get serverUrl in model. Which class i have to import and which function i have to call in my model to get server url. So in future i can easily change my urls in http to https in configuration only.
Something like this.

```
use Zend\View\Helper\BasePath;

abstract class MysqliDB {

    protected function site_url(){

        $object = new BasePath();
        return $object->getView();
    }

}
```

Please Suggest me if i can do this or there any alternative for this.

Comment: I personally do not think that functions, method's and services like these belong within the business logic. But you might be apple to get (MvcEvent $e) then $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager(); then get the router service and then change the server url within it.

Comment: Your model should not instantiate an object an then magically knows about the URL, your model should ask for the URL. The outside layer of the model should then give the URL to it.

Comment: thanks cptnk and Sven, so i have to use factories in module.php to pass server url to my model?

Comment: There are various approaches for this I think. You could use the Module.php. Or create a factory or just define it within your config.

Comment: @cptnk thanks a lot for great help. if you can give me an example it will be much appreciating.

Comment: http://blog.rudylee.com/2013/02/15/zend-framework-2-get-server-url-in-controller-without-using-serverurl/ this should work within your module.php, too. Then you'll only have to give your module a method retrieving that from a controller etc.

Comment: Your model should not know about any urls. Only classes calling your model should know. Your model can accept a param that triggers a certain behaviour according to that parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] for getting the host name/base url for your website.

Comment: Good idea, but what if we want to control https or http from configuration? I meant i want to have an idea of connecting ZF2 configuration to model directly. Currently i am passing url from controller, as a parameter to model.

Comment: You can easily check if the protocol is http or https by using this code echo isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'off' ? 'HTTPS' : 'HTTP';